# JSX Support doesn't work anymore with gulp-eslint 5.0.0

Tags: node.js, gulp, jsx, eslint, gulp-eslint

I have upgraded to current gulp-eslint version 5.0.0.

When i now try to lint my code i get usual errors at the beginning of my JSX code:

`127:26  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =`

I assumed it's an issue with eslint by itself. So i tried to lint my code with a global installed eslint (5.9.0) and got no errors on jsx part. All other linting is identical.

My `eslintrc.json`'s:

```
{
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6
    },
    "rules": {
    },
    "env": {
        "node": true
    }
}
```

And a folder downwards:

```
{
    "extends": ["../.eslintrc.json", "plugin:react/recommended"],
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "pragma": "React",
            "version": "15.0"
        }
    },
    "plugins": ["react"],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 5,
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "node": false,
        "browser": true
    },
    "globals": {
        "angular": true,
        "React": true,
        "ReactDOM": true,
        "Uint8Array": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "jsx-quotes": [1, "prefer-single"],
        "react/prop-types": 0,
        "react/no-deprecated": 0
    }
}
```

Additional info: gulp-eslint 3.x and 4.x works fine with the same configuration.

Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it after hours of searching! It seems there were old dependencies in the `package-lock.json`.

I've deleted the `package-lock.json` und reinstalled all packages with `npm i`. Now it works as expected.